# Java loop to collect the second and third elements every three in an array

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I have a file with data in the form timestamp, coordinate, coordinate, seperated by spaces, as here;

14:25:01.215 370.0 333.0

I need to loop through and add the coordinates only to an array. The data from the file is read in and put into as String[] called info, from split(" "). I have two problems, I think the end of the file has a extra " " which I need to lose appropriately and I also want confirmation/suggestions of my loop, at the moment I am getting sporadic out of bounds exceptions. My loop is as follows;

```
String[] info;
info = dataHolder.split(" ");
ArrayList<String> coOrds1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int counter = 0; counter < info.length; counter = counter+3)
{
    coOrds1.add(info[counter+1]);
    coOrds1.add(info[counter+2]);
}
```

Help and suggestions appreciated.

The text file is [here](http://www.shalomplace.co.uk/PathClient.txt) but the class receives in a UDP packet from another class so I am unsure if this potentially adds " " at the end or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various classes/methods in Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library that could help with this task, in particular `Splitter.omitEmptyStrings()` which will discard any trailing space at the end of the file:

```
String input = Files.toString(file, Charsets.US_ASCII);
Iterable<String> fields =
    Splitter.on(" ")
            .omitEmptyStrings()
            .split(input);
List<Coord> coords = Lists.newArrayList();
for (List<String> group: Iterables.partition(fields, 3)) {
    String t = group.get(0);
    double x = Double.parseDouble(group.get(1));
    double y = Double.parseDouble(group.get(2));
    coords.add(new Coord(t, x, y));
}
```

Comment: I don't think that an external library is needed in the case, this would be a classic example of overusing/depending too much on such libraries. Plus, it would bloat the distributable once it is shipped.
There are perfectly easy & fit-for-the-job solutions using only the standard lib, imho.

Comment: @pnt, I don't think it's overkill in this case as this example benefits from no fewer than four classes from that library.  And as for countering bloat, there's always [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I do agree that more than one class will be utilized from the library. It would be justified to use it if such functionality was not already present. My point was that the library could be entirely omitted and the problem solved elegantly with less loc, using only the std lib.

Answer (score 1):

The problem will occur if you have an extra space at the end, because you are testing for `counter < info.length` and using `counter + 1` and `counter + 2`. Try changing the loop conditions to:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter + 2 < info.length; counter = counter+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for external libraries.

You could just call `dataHolder.trim();` which will remove any whitespace from the beginning and end your string. Then using `dataHolder.split("\s"); //splits on "whitespace"`, you will receive an array consisting only of your data and with the appropriate size.

This will save you all the checks at each iteration whether counter+2 is still within the scope of the array. While still a valid solution, this could introduce further problems in the future due to its inherent nature of being "check-to-validate" - you simply might forget to process one of the cases - while trimming the string beforehand makes it structurally, constructed valid and there is no need to process special cases.